# VM error: revert. Try to send ether from contract to another contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, ethereumjs

I just facing a little issue here in sending some **ether** from **Sender** contract to another contract **Escrow** by **msg.sender** value.

Btw, I'm executing code on Remix, and specify the value from the sender after calling *sendEth()*.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract Sender {
    event sent(
        address indexed escrowAddress
    );
    
    function sendEth() external payable{
        Escrow escrow = new Escrow();
        
        address payable _payableEscrow = address(uint160(address(escrow)));
        _payableEscrow.transfer(msg.value);
        
        emit sent(_payableEscrow);
    }
}

contract Escrow {
    function getBalance() external view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

And IDK why exactly I received this error:

> transact to Sender.sendEth errored: VM error: revert.
>
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in the `Escrow` contract a `payable` fallback function to accept or reject the funds:

```
function() external payable {
    // you can reject the funds (assert/require/revert) under certain conditions...
}
```